# Page keeps loading while recording through jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to record a .net application through jmeter. While navigation the application manually, it's working. When I start recording through jmeter, page keeps loading.
I've checked the proxy, certificate as well.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Always take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), normally it contains either the reason or at least a clue so you will be able to figure out what went wrong.

It worth enabling JMeter debug logging for the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
```

Also pay attention to "Console" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools), if something is wrong on the client/browser side - it will tell you what exactly.

And last but not the least: there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), it's less "invasive" and you won't need to worry about proxies and certificates.